# How to pass the steam age check using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with curl. I wanna tried to access a steam game page by using curl but I have to pass the age check. The problem that how to click the button in order to go to the game page because curl can't load javascript. Here is my code.

```
$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/312660/";
$file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "cookie.txt";
$postData = array(
'ageDay' => '31',
'ageMonth' => 'July',
'ageYear' => '1993'
);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$file); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$file);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Does anyone here can help me to by pass the age verification system which implemented by Valve? Anyway, is it possible to do clicking the button by using curl method? Thank you.

Comment: yeah, I am still learning about programming, I really need a hand.

Comment: post var_dump($data), what you have in response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code, now you will get the game video because we r forcing the cookie. So you won't see the age restriction screen

```
<?php
$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/312660/";
// $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "cookie.txt";
// $postData = array(
// 'ageDay' => '31',
// 'ageMonth' => 'July',
// 'ageYear' => '1993'
// );
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);
// curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
// curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$file); 
// curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$file);
$strCookie = 'mature_content=' . 1 . '; path=/';
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: how do you know the cookie?

$strCookie = 'mature_content=' . 1 . '; path=/';

Comment: debug the java script call during the button click. It invokes a function

Answer (score 0):

The check box selection and continue button click is not submitting any post data / form submission. It simply sets a cookie and redirects to the location http://store.steampowered.com/app/312660/.

So in your curl call to the location http://store.steampowered.com/app/312660/agecheck . Set the required cookie and invoke this URL, you will be redirected to the above URL with game video starts playing hhtml content u will get in response.

You can do the same by setting the cookie, so that you will see the video playing page

Comment: May I know how to set the cookie? Would be great if you can make a sample. Thank you